# Convert double to int array

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, int, double

I have a double

```
double pi = 3.1415;
```

I want to convert this to a int array

```
int[] piArray = {3,1,4,1,5};
```

I came up with this

```
double pi = 3.1415;
String piString = Double.toString(pi).replace(".", "");
int[] piArray = new int[piString.length()];
for (int i = 0; i <= piString.length()-1; i++)
   piArray[i] = piString.charAt(i) - '0';
```

It's working but I don't like this solution because I think a lot of conversions between datatypes can lead to errors. Is my code even complete or do I need to check for something else?

And how would you approach this problem?

Comment: You might be interested in base 2 digits, a double as array of 0s and 1s. The Double class has conversion of the **bits**. Above you could have the power-of-ten in the array: -4 in your example. Doubles are themselves problematic, as the toString could well give "3.14149999998"

Comment: Thought about writing a Java 7 answer, but it seems pointless. A foreach of `piString.toCharArray` and using `Character::getNumericValue` are the only changes I'd make. Edit: would still need indexes for the int array...

Comment: What should happend if the number is big? I mean: if the string representation of a number is `1E200` do you want the array to become `{1,2,0,0}` or `{1,0,0,0,0,...,0}` with 200 zeros?

Comment: What answer do you expect for (say) `double d = 0.1`? Due to floating point shenanigans this is far from trivial. Furthermore, why do you think that conversion between data types leads to errors? — And lastly, for the future, such questions are better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: We might be able to give a more meaningful answer if we understood why you are doing this?  What will you be doing with the resulting array?

Comment: While you can do this, I suspect whatever you are trying to achieve would be done more efficiently another way.

Comment: Excuse me, but the real question should be "convert double to decimal int array wihout String conversion"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't know straight way but I think it is simpler:

```
int[] piArray = String.valueOf(pi)
                      .replaceAll("\\D", "")
                      .chars()
                      .map(Character::getNumericValue)
                      .toArray();
```

Comment: Came up with the same solution, you were a bit earlier :)

Comment: I have used `replaceAll("\\D", "")` tough to filter any non digits.

Comment: Glains post your solution or edit, as i think it's the more robust solution.

Comment: @RahimDastar since a `double` has a single `.`, use `replaceFirst` instead of `replaceAll`, otherwise 1+

Comment: @Eugene if double is 1.13E+21 replaceFirst is not working

Comment: @Eugene I came up with the idea of `,` or `.` as separator (american or european standard) and those could also be used multiple times like `1.000,12`. This would cover all cases, you wont know how this will be used in the future...

Comment: @Glains indeed, did not think of that initially

Comment: `BigDecimal.valueOf(pi).toPlainString()` avoids the exponential form altogether.

Answer (score 13):

Since you want to avoid casts, here's the arithmetic way, supposing you only have to deal with positive numbers :

```
List<Integer> piList = new ArrayList<>();
double current = pi;
while (current > 0) {
    int mostSignificantDigit = (int) current;
    piList.add(mostSignificantDigit);
    current = (current - mostSignificantDigit) * 10;
}
```

Handling negative numbers could be easily done by checking the sign at first then using the same code with `current = Math.abs(pi)`.

Note that due to floating point arithmetics it will give you results you might not expect for values that can't be perfectly represented in binary.

[Here](https://ideone.com/cGIb4H)'s an ideone which illustrates the problem and where you can try my code.

Comment: I can’t believe this is the only answer that even mentions floating-point representation. +1

Comment: While the arithmetic approach is nice, the problem with imprecise floating point representations makes this pretty useless for real world numbers. When `3.1415` produces a `List` with 52 values (3, 1, 4, 1, 5, a bunch of zeroes, then what amounts to useless garbage "precision"), you're violating user expectations quite a bit.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes, definitely agreed. I "remembered" floating point precision problems when testing my solution, and thought my answer would still be of interest anyway (especially if it's homework, in which case I wouldn't be surprised if this problem was what the teacher wanted his students to encounter). A real world arithmetics solution  would still be possible by using `BigDecimal`, but I'm not sure it would have many advantages over the string-based solutions

Comment: @Aaron: Yeah. If the value arrives as a `double`, you end up with the same problems converting to `BigDecimal`; `BigDecimal`'s constructor for `double` preserves the exact decimal representation of the binary floating point value, so the only way `BigDecimal` helps is if you can change your input type to `BigDecimal` (pushing the problem to the caller), or perform implicit rounding through string conversion (which just hides the fact that it's all effectively based on string parsing). Your answer isn't wrong (not down-voting), it's just probably not useful for anything but demonstration.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The string solution fundamentally *also* has this problem; it’s less pronounced since the string formatter already provides some handling for it, but it still exists. In a way the string solution just hides a potential bug better, and this is not generally a good idea.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Sort of. If the value was entered by a user, at least in modern Python (not sure if Java makes the same effort), the string form is always minimal (the shortest string that, if interpreted as a literal, would produce the same binary floating point value). If Java and Python match behavior, explicitly entered `double`s will work as expected. The problem would arise for *computed* `double`s, where the numbers spawn undesired precision (e.g. `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004`, not `0.3`).

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] result = Stream.of(pi)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.split("\\.|")))
            .filter(x -> !x.isEmpty())
            .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
            .toArray();
```

Or a safer approach with `java-9`:

```
 int[] result = new Scanner(String.valueOf(pi))
            .findAll(Pattern.compile("\\d"))
            .map(MatchResult::group)
            .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
            .toArray();
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is safer, would be interested in that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use in java 8

```
int[] piArray = piString.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

this would work also

```
int[] piArray = piString.chars().map(c -> c-'0').toArray();
```

Answer (score -2):

This solution makes no assumptions and uses string manipulation to get you the result you want. Gets the double, turns it to a string, removes illegal characters, then casts each of the remaining characters into ints and stores them in the array - in the order they appear in the double

```
        double pi           = 3.1415;
        String temp         = ""+ pi;
        String str          = "";
        String validChars   = "0123456789";

        //this removes all non digit characters 
        //so '.' and '+' and '-' same as string replace(this withThat)
        for(int i =0; i<temp.length(); i++){
          if(validChars.indexOf(temp.charAt(i)) > -1 ){
              str = str +temp.charAt(i);
          }
        }

        int[] result = new int[str.length()];

        for(int i =0; i<str.length(); i++){
          result[i] = Integer.parseInt(""+str.charAt(i));
          System.out.print(result[i]);
        }

        return result; //your array of ints
```